# how to declare variable like this-- ArrayList LinkedhashMap

Tags: java, scjp

[image]

how to declare variable like this-- ArrayList LinkedhashMap.

Comment: You mean something like `ArrayList<Map<K, V>>` ?

Comment: do you mean ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<key, value>>() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<KeyType, ValueType>> maps;
```

`KeyType` and `ValueType` are placeholders, I don't know the real types. And the real declaration should use interfaces. But that's the closest to answer your question.

(The better declaration:

```
Map<String, List<Map<KeyType, ValueType>> maps;
```

We map lists of maps to string values. That's the explanation for this datastructure
)

Answer (score 2):

**Well if you are using Java 1.5 or greater , you can  make use of Generics**

```
//This approach is type safe.
List<LinkedHashMap<KeyType,ValueType>> myListOfMaps  = ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<KeyType, ValueType>>();
```

**for Java less that 1.5 use normal Arraylist.**

```
List myListOfMaps  = new ArrayList (); //But with this approach its not type safe , 
                                    //because any object type can be inserted
```

**Now to create a Map of ListsofMaps**

```
Map<String, List<Map<KeyType, ValueType>> maps = new HashMap <String, List<Map<KeyType, ValueType>>();
maps.put("rows",myListOfMaps  );
```

This link  will give you [Why Use Generics ?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Check this [Generic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for more info